# Show that $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|+1}$ is a bijection from R to (-1,1).

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm not sure how to do this, I get stuck because $x$ is both in the numerator and denominator, and because of the absolute value. How do I show injectivity and surjectivity for the following?

Show that $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|+1}$ is a bijection from R to (-1,1). (where R is the set of real numbers).

Comment: $f(x) < 0$ iff $x<0$ and $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and $|f(x)|<1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Monotonicity is useless here and you may compute $f^{-1}$ explicitely. First check that $f$ indeed takes its values in $(-1,1)$, and then, for any $y\in(-1,1)$, solve the equation $f(x)=y$ by an elementary computation (the solution was given in the 3rd and last answer to the question linked above by AnotherUser).

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x) = \pm 1$ and $|f| <1$, you can conclude that $f(\mathbb{R}) = (-1,1)$.

On the other hand, since
$$
f'(x)= \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2} & x >0 \\[1em] \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}& x <0\end{cases},
$$

you conclude that $f'(x)> 0$ for all $x \ne 0$ and so $f$ is strictly increasing.

From these two facts, you can deduce that $f$ is a bijection between the mentioned sets.

Answer (score 0):

You may start by taking the drivative of the function and see what happens.
$$y'=\frac{1.(|x|+1)-x.\frac{|x|}{x}}{(|x|+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(|x|+1)^2}$$
when $x\neq 0$.

Since $y'>0$, the function is strictly increasing for $x<0$ and $x>0$. But, the function $y$ is continuous for all $x$, so it is strictly increasing on ${R}$. Hence, it is injective.

For surjectivity, given $y$, we can solve for $x$ as J.G. commented. But we must be carefull. (i) If $x<0$, $x=\frac{y}{1+y}$. But then, $-1<y<0$. (ii) If $x>0$, $x=\frac{y}{1-y}$. But then, $0<y<1$. (iii) $x=0$ iff $y=0$. from i, ii and iii, we can deduce that the image of that function is $(-1,1)$.